# Width Constraint Applied in Preview but not in Simulator

Tags: swift, autolayout

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1UnM.jpg) of the issue. Left side is the simulator. Right is the Preview.

I have more or less the same constraints applied to each of these lines. They each have a width (or height) constraint of 1. For some reason the simulator adds +1 width to one of the the bottom left lines.

Is this an issue with the simulator that anyone else has experienced? Is there actually something I've done wrong in Auto Layout?

Comment: The simulator can be aligned between pixels. The thicker line you're seeing here shouldn't show up on a device.

Comment: Hey @JackWu, just tried it on my device and it is still showing up. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Interesting, maybe you do have a constraint that's incorrect. I can't really help you without more info on your setup. Have you tried using view debugging to see if anything fishy is going on? See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html.